# Intellij Idea: One line if on two lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

So I am new to the Intellij Idea IDE and so far I like it a lot. Just having some trouble getting the code style settings exactly how I like them for Java. I am a fan of not using braces for one line if statements but I like for them to be on two lines:

```
if(true)
    dosomething();
```

Right now when I run code formatting in Idea, it moves up into one line:

```
if(true) dosomething();
```

and I find that very hard to read, but I cannot seem to get the settings just right. Can anyone help me out and tell me what I need to set to keep it on two lines but still no braces? Feel pretty dumb not being able to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Deselect `Simple blocks in one line` in settings -> CodeStyle -> WrappingandBraces, then it should work. It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I have that unchecked, but it seems with 'Force braces' as 'Do not force' for if() statements it just shrinks them back down. And any other selection for 'Force braces' puts them in for one-liners.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Control Statements on one line? Does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might sound strange, but even I had the option `simple blocks in one line` unchecked. And I was facing same issue. But then if I left one empty line after the opening brace of method, IntelliJ didn't move entire code to one line.

For better understanding,

1. Problematic behavior

   ```
   public void methodA(){ 
       System.out.println("No blank line left");
   }
   ```

   Now when you close and open the file again, IntelliJ does this

   ```
   public void methodA(){ System.out.println("No blank line left"); }
   ```
2. Correct Behavior

   ```
   public void methodA(){ 

       System.out.println("left a blank line above");
   }
   ```

   Now when you close and open the file again, it still stays like that

   ```
   public void methodA(){ 

       System.out.println("left a blank line above"); 
   }
   ```

Just to make a note, IntelliJ version is Ultimate 14.1.4

Answer (score 0):

For [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - IntelliJ for Javascript, this option is in `Preferences->Editor->Code Style -> Javascript-> Wrapping and Braces`.